# Android: Detect when user chooses a number (he wishes to call) in the contacts list?

Tags: android, service, contacts

I'm trying to get an Android background service to be "notified" when the user chooses a phone number (he wishes to call) from the phone's contacts list. My goal with this is to prevent the system from placing the call and present a user with a choice dialog, then go from there... Need help.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do what I asked yesterday, so I'm sharing it here for anyone interested. The trick was, to catch the NEW_OUTGOING_CALL broadcasted intent in a BroadcastReceiver and not any event related to the choosing of contacts, as I was thinking.

So... follow the steps.

In the application element of the AndroidManifest.xml file add a receiver element... The android:name attribute is the class that will extend from BroadcastReceiver (explained below).

```
<receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallDetection">
```

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
  android:priority="0" />
```

ahh! And you'll need a special permission...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

The onReceive method in the class that extends BroadcastReceiver (OutgoingCallDetection in this example). Note that setResultData(null) is what prevents the call from being made by the system itself.

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    setResultData(null);

    // Start an activity and then show a dialog, or something...

}
```

Here it is, and working as needed.